# Pandas.cut specify custom range

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to specify a custom range in `pandas.cut`?

I have a dataset where I need to bin the age column (and several other columns). The `min` and the `max` value of `age` in the dataset is `18` and `55`, respectively. However, in the documentation of the dataset, it is written that the range of the attribute `age` is `18-58`.

`pandas.cut` will automatically bin according to the range of the dataset (which will be `18-55`), which is wrong.

Is there any way I can specify the range to bin on in the `pandas.cut` method? I looked into `IntervalIndex` tuples as bins, but that would mean that I generate the bins manually myself. I am looking for if `pandas.cut` has this functionality built-in.

Comment: Please provide a more concrete example, and then we can tell you whether what you want is possible or not. Suggestion: [mcve]. And please indicate your input + expected output. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly.

However, you could pass `np.linspace(18, 58, n_bins)` to `pd.cut`. I'm not sure if you consider that "generating manually".